# Naïve Tiled Matrix Multiplication with Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to write a function to perform the matrix multiplication operation on two large matrices that are split up into smaller matrices (tiles), and I'm having difficulty conceptualizing a valid approach.

In the script below, two tensors/matrices, `a` and `b`, are segmented into multiple sub-tensors/matrices (tiles) of shape `tile_shape`. Given these tiles, I would like to perform operations that give the same result as a.dot(b), i.e., vector-matrix multiplication.

For simplicity sake, tiles are all the same shape, and are zero padded for cases where the length/width of a given tensor is not divisible by `tile shape`. I would like the approach to be modular, so that any given valid input shapes and tile shapes can be specified.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import math

class Tiles:
    def __init__(self, tiles, tensor_shape):
        self.tiles = tiles
        self.tile_shape = tiles.shape[-2:]
        self.tensor_shape = tensor_shape

def gen_tiles(tensor, tile_shape):
    assert len(tensor.shape) == 2
    tiles = np.empty((math.ceil(tensor.shape[0] / tile_shape[0]), math.ceil(tensor.shape[1] / tile_shape[1]), tile_shape[0], tile_shape[1]))
    for i in range(0, tiles.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, tiles.shape[1]):
            tile = tensor[i * tile_shape[0]:max((i + 1) * tile_shape[0], tile_shape[0] - 1), j * tile_shape[1]:max((j + 1) * tile_shape[1], tile_shape[1] - 1)]
            padded_tile = np.zeros(shape=tile_shape)
            padded_tile[:tile.shape[0],:tile.shape[1]] = tile
            tiles[i][j][:][:] = padded_tile

    return Tiles(tiles, tensor.shape)

def matmul_tiles(a, b):
    assert a.tensor_shape[1] == b.tensor_shape[0] and a.tile_shape == b.tile_shape
    result = np.zeros((a.tensor_shape[0], b.tensor_shape[1]))
    print(a.tiles.shape[0:2])
    print(b.tiles.shape[0:2])
    # Compute matrix multiplication using tiles

tile_shape = (2, 2)
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 2))
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 3))
a_tiles = gen_tiles(a, tile_shape)
b_tiles = gen_tiles(b, tile_shape)
product = a.dot(b)
tile_product = matmul_tiles(a_tiles, b_tiles)
assert np.isclose(product, tile_product)
```

Comment: I'm curious on why you want doing it? Did you want implement the `Dot` operation?

Comment: Working with 2d tiles appears to be a complicated task.  It would be a lot simpler (I think) if you worked with chunks of rows for one variable, and columns in the other.  This would be closer to the manual method - scanning across the rows and down the columns.